# html5 video works from any file on my computer except for localhost

Tags: html, html5-video, wamp, mp4, ogg

I am trying to play some html5 videos on a webpage.  I am using WAMP 2.2 and PHP 5.3.10.  I have tried both the .ogv format and the .mp4 format.  This works fine when I do it client-side (not on localhost), but when I try to do it server side (from localhost), in Firefox I get a blanked out video with the message "No video supported format and MIME type found".  In Chrome I get an unplayable video, and in IE, I also get an unplayable video.  I put in to `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\httpd.conf` these lines at the bottom of the file:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg

AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/webm .weba

AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
```

And I restarted wamp and tried again, and I still had the same problem.  What do I have to do to run either .ogv, .mp4, or another one of these html5 video formats?

Comment: have you added the MIME types to your .htaccess file yet?

Comment: Could it be that you server machine does have the codecs and your client machine does?

Comment: No, I just added:

AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg

AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/webm .weba

AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v

to the bottom of C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\httpd.conf.  I searched for htaccess under C:\wamp, and the search returned several files.  Which htaccess do I add the MIME types to?  And how do I do it?  The same way as I did in httpd.conf?  And do I also need those extra lines I put at the bottom of httpd.conf?

Comment: @Danish Could be - if that's the case where can I find the html5 codecs I need and where to I store them or how can I set them up to work on my localhost running on WAMP 2.2 and PHP 5.3.10?

Comment: Looked around and found this. It has test videos as well, so you check if my guess is correct or not! :) - http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/15/how-to-add-missing-html5-video-support-to-your-browser/

Comment: are you getting a 206 response? if so disble partial content in htaccess as this can cause issues when operating locally